# Get last character on didExceedMaxLines

Tags: flutter, dart

So I used a text painter to write my text for a book like reader, and can now tell if the text exceeds the max line I set for it, only problem is that I want to know at what character or string index it stopped painting so that I can paint the rest on the next page, any help will be appreciated

Comment: you need `TextPainter.getBoxesForSelection` method - it returns a list of `TextBox` that you need to check when the given box crosses your page

Comment: can u help explain it abit, I havnt been able to understand it until now, the inserting a selection into the method part

Comment: `getBoxesForSelection` returns a list, you need to iterate over that list and stop iterating when `box.bottom` exceeds the height of your page - this is the line of text that cannot be shown completely and is cut at the bottom by your page